# Does $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N) = 0$ imply $\text{Tor}_j^R(M,N) = 0$ for $j > i$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am looking at the Tor functor for $R$-modules $M,N$. If, for example, $M$ or $N$ is flat  then $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N) = 0$ for all $i > 0$ so this functor can be seen as a "measure" of flatness (and it makes sense that a few criteria for flatness can be stated in terms of Tor, as in Eisenbud)

But I was wondering, does it precisely measure failure of exactness under tensor producting at the $i$-th resolution? That is to say, if $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N) = 0$ for the first time at $i = 3$, then should it be understood that $ -\otimes M $ preserves exactness only until the third resolution? Since if $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N) = 0$ at $i = 2$ lets say, then we know $\text{ker}(\varphi_2) = \text{Im}(\varphi_3)$ in our free (projective) resolution so exactness at the 2nd spot was preserved. And, if $\text{Tor}_i^R(M,N) = 0$ then is $\text{Tor}_j^R(M,N) = 0$ for $j > i$ as well?

Some examples suggest that, as
$$\text{Tor}_i^R(R/(x), M) = \begin{cases}
M/xM & i = 0, \\
\text{ann}(M) & i = 1, \\
0 & i > 1
\end{cases}$$
And also $$ \text{Tor}_i^R(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb{Z}/(m,n)\mathbb{Z} & i = 0,1 \\
0 & i > 1
\end{cases} $$
But I don't see how to prove it, apriori I don't see any reason for it to be true besides these examples.

Comment: Note that there’s only one resolution, which is the complex. So what you mean by “the third resolution” is rather obscure. Note also that $Tor_j^R(M,N)=0$ doesn’t say much on $-\otimes M$: it only says something on the pair $(M,N)$.

Comment: I’m confident that the answer to the question is negative, but finding counter-examples is nontrivial: you need $M,N$ to have projective dimension at least $2$ (so no Dedekind rings) and $i \geq 1$. But we can’t have $i=1$ and $M$ the residue field of a Noetherian local ring, because this implies that $N$ is flat.

Comment: The key word here is rigidity of Tor.